# How to repeat a for loop

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I have got one problem with Python. I'm trying to repeat a for loop more than once. I have a condition inside the loop, and if the condition is true, the loop should start again. I need the solution only with one for loop. For example:

```
for i in range (10):
    if i==4:
        i=0
    print(i)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

The output should be: `0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3...`

Comment: OP, what you are trying to do sounds like a bad idea in general. Structured programming doesn't usually work well with `goto`, `continue` and `break`, much less randomly fiddling with the loop index. There is a [famous historic paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) on the subject. Also, consider `print [x % 4 for x in range(10)]`for a more pythonic way :)

Comment: @TobiaTesan What's wrong with `continue` and `break`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 maybe `filter` and `next` are better abstractions.

Comment: @mkrieger1: there is *a lot* of literature about it, from the EWD paper to [this one](http://homepages.tig.com.au/~ijoyner/Ian_Joyner/Structured_Programming.html). TL;DR the main contention point is that early exit generally undermines structured programming which is at its cleanest with exactly 1 entry and 1 exit point. Of course there are times when a `break` here and there is actually a good idea, but I suspect it's better that **OP stays away from them for the time being**.

Comment: I have tried it with while,but TLE,so there'll be problem with my algorithm maybe

Answer (score 4):

Writing to the loop's variable (`i`) inside the loop is always not a good idea (that includes all languages I'm familiar with).

Try using a while loop instead:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    if i == 4:
        i = 0
```

The same logic can be implemented with:

```
while True:
    for i in range(4):
        print(i)
```

Or using the modulo operator which is common when cycling:

```
i = 0
while True:
    print(i % 4)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting the through away variable `i` to 0 at the bottom level of the loop doesn't mean that in next iteration your variable shall be 0, because in each iteration python reassigned it automatically.

As a more pythonic way for such tasks you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
>>> def range_printer(r,N): # r is the length of your range and N is the number of sequence printing 
...     a=cycle(range(r))
...     for i in range(N*r):
...         print next(a)
... 
>>> range_printer(4,3)
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
```

Or you can use `yield` to return a generator :

```
>>> def range_printer(r,N):
...     a=cycle(range(r))
...     for i in range(N*r):
...         yield next(a)
... 
>>> list(range_printer(4,3))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Still itertools.cycle is probably what OP wants / should use.

Comment: And you cant really change i variable as it is dynamically yielded by range.

Comment: Why people always say you can't change (rebind) i?? Of course you can. Set i to 8 before printing, and you'll see 8 printed. The only thing is that range yields the next value independently of what i is set to.

Comment: @Veky Indeed but that's another scenario, pls check the edit! and thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2):

a version using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

for i in cycle(range(4)):
    # put your logic that `break`s the cycle here
    print(i)
```